# Schedule email sending time in apple Mail 6.2

Tags: scheduled-tasks, apple-mail

Is it possible to schedule the time that an email is sent in Mail so it can be sent when I'm away from my desk (I'm running v6.2 in Mountain Lion)

Answer (score 0):

Check [SendLater](http://www.chungwasoft.com/sendlater/) or [Mail Scheduler Pro](http://www.mrose.nl/mail-scheduler-pro.html).